# Adding special expressions in blender

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, game-engine

I have to add special effects once the game is completed.
Like medal popping out or confetti when the winner is declared.
The game is simple wrestling game in which two players are controlled using keys on keyboard.
**Do I need to use python script for medal popping effect or confetti once the winner is declared** ?


**If yes,How can I achieve this?**

Comment: No, you do not need to use Python. You can use Python.

Comment: I do not see where your problem is. Is it that you do not know how to create this effects? Is it you do not know how to configure the effects that they show at the right moment?

I suggest you rephrase the question into: "How to create a confetti effect?". You might ask a separate question "How to let a medal pop up?".

Comment: @Monster  I want a medal to pop up just after the game is completed

Comment: How do you know the game is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popping medal:

activate an edit actuator in Add Object mode

[image]

Comment: How can I set the time?

Comment: What time do you mean?